# how to configure Delphi 2010 ISAPI.dll in IIS7 64bit?

Tags: delphi, iis-7, isapi

what are minimal steps required to make ISAPI dll working in IIS7 for query www.website.com/test/bin/ISAPIGet.dll?a=b ? Please don't refer to top google searches, they are very generic and don't work.
I wrote very simple ISAPIGet.dll in Delphi2010, which works great in IIS5 Win2000. Then I put it on IIS7 SBS2008, 
into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\website\test\bin folder. 
Created website for /website, 
Application for /test, 
VirtualDirectory for /bin, 
in HandlerMappings for /bin Added Script Map *.dll to my ISAPIGet.dll, 
allowed my dll in ISAPIandCgiRestrictions, 
created 32bit ApplicationPool NonManaged code, Classic mode, 
bound it to /test Application.
When quering www.website.com/test/bin/ISAPIGet.dll?a=b I'm getting all kinds of errors like 500, 503 (when AppPool fails), while homepage www.website.com is working fine.
What else should I do? Do I need to configure web.config file, where and how?

Comment: What your server log says about the errors?

Comment: You are supposed to capture crash dump and analyze, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580960

Comment: I disagree that the question is too ambiguous.  99/100 step-by-step tutorials on the web miss key steps to add a 32-bit ISAPI dll to IIS7.  Having gone through the same frustration as the OP 2 years ago, his question makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

As I recall, I had similar problems getting our ISAPI DLL to run in IIS7 on WinSvr2008R2(64b).  I wrote down some quick notes to help me repeat the steps that finally got it working.  I'll try to provide those here (at least what we did).

1. Grant "Read & Execute, List folder contents, and Read" rights to IUSR to the folder `C:\PathToISAPI_DLL`
2. Copy all DLL files that the ISAPI DLL needs to run into the `c:\windows\syswow64` folder (e.g., midas.dll, dbxmss.dll, etc.)
3. Start IIS Manager
4. Add the app pool "MyAppPool" [no managed, classic, start now]
5. Change "Advanced Settings" of new App Pool to allow 32-bit, plus set idle time-out
6. Add an application "MyApp" to your website using "MyAppPool" and set the physical path to `C:\PathToISAPI_DLL`

Now you have to do several steps at the DOS prompt to finish configuring things:

```
cd /d c:\windows\system32\inetsrv

REM *** Grant rights to execute the DLL ***
appcmd.exe set config -section:isapiCgiRestriction /+[path='C:\PathToISAPI_DLL\ISAPI.dll',allowed='true']

REM *** Grant the url of the Execute access for hander mappings ***
appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/MyApp/ISAPI.DLL" "/commit:Default Web Site/MyApp" /section:handlers /accessPolicy:Read,Script,Execute

REM *** Make sure you have an ISAPI module mapping for *.dll at that path ***
appcmd.exe list config "Default Web Site/MyApp" /section:handlers | findstr /i *.dll
```

That's the extent of my notes.  I have successfully followed them several times and it has always worked.  I have **never** been able to get it work using just the GUI.  I've **always** had to run the `appcmd` commands at a DOS prompt to finish configuring things.

Sometimes I still see a 404 error, in which case I delete the web.config from the folder with the ISAPI.DLL and run the last two `appcmd` commands again.  Of course, my ISAPI DLL doesn't have any other settings in the web.config file so it doesn't hurt to just delete it...

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just because the dll is 32 bit and IIS7 is a 64 bit process so is not able to read a Delphi 32 bit dll?

Your main page is static html which is handled by IIS with no problem.

But when IIS tries to load `ISAPIGet.dll`, it fails because it is not a 64 bit library, or one of its dependency is missing.

- Are you *sure* you use a IIS7 app-pool in 32-bit mode?
- Do you have all needed sub-libraries and bpl in the same path or in c:\windows\syswow64 ?