# How to run ISAPI dll on Windows 7?

Tags: delphi, iis, web-applications, webserver, isapi

With Delphi 2010 XE, I created a sample ISAPI dll application. I want to test run this file on my local machine. How can I do that? I searched my machine for the path to my LOCALHOST and found out that it is suppose to be %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, but when I place the dll file there and try to access it (localhost/WebInterfaceForm/Welcome), webbrowser complains it can't find WebInterfaceForm dll file.

So, how is this done on Windows 7?

Comment: an answer to a closed question might help [how to configure Delphi 2010 ISAPI.dll in IIS7 64bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264456/1699210)

Comment: Are you familiar with IIS?

Comment: The folder you have put your DLL in has nothing to do with IIS. You need to make sure that `Internet Information Services` is installed in `Turn Windows features on and off`. IIRC, typically the IIS folder is in `c:\inetpub` or something along those lines.

Comment: Is Windows 7 a server operating system? ;)

Comment: @mjn No Its not, but it does have IIS installed and running.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yes, I am somewhat familiar with it but not an expert.

Comment: @bummi Thanks for the link... I will have to try it soon.